# Error "Something is wrong; all the RMSE metric values are missing" using SBC from frbs package in Caret

Tags: r, r-caret

I've been trying to fit a model using 'SBC' method from 'frbs' package in Caret for R. I've seen similar questions in SO for different packages and tried the solutions but they didn't seem to work in my case. I've provided a code snippet for reproducability using iris dataset.

```
library(caret)
data("iris")
grid<-expand.grid(r.a = c(0.5),
                                     eps.high = c(0.5),
                                     eps.low = c(0))

Fit <- train(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width + Petal.Length + Petal.Width, data = iris,
                                 method = "SBC", 
                               #  trControl = fitControl,
                                 tuneGrid=grid,
                                 verbose = TRUE)

Fit$results
```

The error obtained is :

```
Something is wrong; all the RMSE metric values are missing:
      RMSE        Rsquared  
 Min.   : NA   Min.   : NA  
 1st Qu.: NA   1st Qu.: NA  
 Median : NA   Median : NA  
 Mean   :NaN   Mean   :NaN  
 3rd Qu.: NA   3rd Qu.: NA  
 Max.   : NA   Max.   : NA  
 NA's   :3     NA's   :3    
Error in train.default(x, y, weights = w, ...) : Stopping
In addition: There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)
```

I checked the warnings() and it shows "model fit failed for Resample17: r.a=0.5, eps.high=0.5, eps.low=0 Error in frbs.learn(data.train = structure(c(3.5, 3, 3.2, 3.1, 3.4, 3.4,  : .....". I've even tried installing frbs package separately. Also i've ensured that the classes of the variables are not factors, even for my data.

My question is how can I fix this error and why does this error occur. Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: not reproducible, it works as expected in my machine

Comment: try coercing the `predictor` variables to  `factor` type and see if that works?

Comment: @sandipan So could this error be machine dependent? the same code is working on my colleague's system too. Anything else I can try?

Comment: @Aramis7d Since the method is for regression, converting it into factors shows an error `Error in train.default(x, y, weights = w, ...) : 
  wrong model type for classification`

Comment: may be, you may like to compare your and your colleague's  R version / caret version / OS version etc.

Comment: @snair1591 I guess it thinks of it as classification because you convert all variables to factor. if you leave the `response` variable, i.e. `y` out as numeric, it should be usable for regression.

Comment: @sandipan So I verified with my colleague and versions seems to be same. I can't figure out why such a simple code is not working in mine. I've trained my dataset with gbm and pls before and they have ran successfully.

Comment: @Aramis7d I tried as you suggested and converted all others excpet y (i.e. Sepal.Length in the example) into factor. The classification error didn't come, but the original error still remains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue has been resolved, thanks to Max Kuhn, author of Caret package. The link to the solution in Caret's github page is given [here](http://github.com/topepo/caret/issues/539).